# Use of 'what?' to end an assertion

Tags: history

I'm interested in the colonial English habit of ending an assertive statement with the question "What?", as if asking for agreement from the listener. For example:

> Pleasant weather. What?

What is the history of this phenomenon? It sounds rather comical to modern ears.

Comment: Could you give some examples of this? Your description is not quite clear enough to figure out what kind of context this would be used in.

Comment: As in: 'Pleasant weather, what?'.

Comment: I'm trying to find a clip where Hugh Laurie says this while playing Bertie Wooster, since Wodehouse used this a lot.

Comment: The meaning (such as it is) is 'wouldn't you agree?', but 'what?' affords less opportunity to disagree with the statement. Jeeves always finds a way to register disagreement where necessary: 'If you say so, sir' is his version of 'Balderdash!'

Comment: @KaiserOctavius Well, now I know what I'm doing with the rest of the evening, what.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've no reason to think this usage was ever particularly "colonial English". I suspect it probably originated among Victorian gentry in the motherland.

Moving on to *total* speculation, I think it most likely started as a shortening of *"What do you say?"*, *"What do you think of that, then?"*, etc. Effectively, it's no different to modern usages whereby we append an interjection such as *"Huh?"*, *"Yeah?"*, or (really modern! :) *"Innit?"* to a statement.

I also suspect it was never particularly common at *any* time or place, except as a facetious usage.

Comment: Sort of like our Canadian 'eh', eh?

Comment: @Carole: And [Wisconsin "Yah"](http://www.folklib.net/history/scansin.shtml), hmm?.

Comment: Pragmatic marker subset _have the final say without appearing to_.

Comment: I was thinking that maybe OP was confusing colonial with colloquial, but I wasn't terribly sure.

Answer (score 1):

The *OED* has this as sense 4.c. of ["what, *pron.*, *adj.¹*, and *adv.*, *int.*, *conj.*, and *n.*"](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/228078): "...an interrogative expletive (sometimes with *eh*)... esp. in recent trivial or affected colloq. use".

First attested use? A diary recounting the Mad King's ravings:

> **19 Dec. 1785** F. Burney's *Diary*, Vol. II, p. 398:
>
> [George III] said,—‘What? what?’—meaning, what say you?.. ‘..it is not possible. Do you think it is?—what?’